# Create a custom map projection in d3.js for EASE-Grid

Tags: javascript, d3.js, geo, map-projections

I'm trying to create 3 different projections for the EASE-Grid projection:

http://nsidc.org/data/ease/ease_grid.html#nh_map

Northern Hemisphere Azimuthal Equal-Area Projection, Southern Hemisphere Azimuthal Equal-Area Projection
, and Global Cylindrical Equal-Area Projection.

I know you can create a custom projection in d3.js but how do i even start this? Any help would be awesome!

Comment: There's some help at the bottom of [this page](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo-projection/).

Comment: [This conversation](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/d3-js/OSp_sMZjfok/9e1OdqdgG7sJ) on gg might help with the custom projection.  Also, there might be some information on [Jason Davies](http://www.jasondavies.com/) page.